# Deleted package doesn't reappear in the package list

Tags: magit, package, list-packages

I just deleted `magit`, but it doesn't reappear in the list as available. I typed `g` and `r`, restarted `emacs`, to no effect. It's not hidden. I use `C-s` to search for it in the buffer. Supposedly its dependencies are installed:

```
async              1.9.4         dependency Asynchronous processing in Emacs
dash               2.17.0        dependency A modern list library for Emacs
ghub               3.3.0         dependency Minuscule client libraries for Git forge APIs.
git-commit         2.90.1        dependency Edit Git commit messages
magit-popup        2.13.2        dependency Define prefix-infix-suffix command combos
treepy             0.1.1         dependency Generic tree traversal tools
with-editor        2.9.2         dependency Use the Emacsclient as $EDITOR
```

The relevant part of the `~/.emacs` is supposedly:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (magit))))
```

And there's no `magit` directory in `~/.emacs.d/elpa`.

I didn't delete `magit` directory by hand. Supposedly I did `d x` in the `list-packages` buffer.

I'm running Emacs 26.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** make sure MELPA archive is added (if you need `magit`)

I realized that `magit` is not in ELPA, it's in MELPA. I think I added MELPA archive back then, but that part of the config was supposedly lost owing to running several instances of Emacs, and `orgmode` editing the `~/.emacs` file (adding agenda files).